# Rails 4 - Endpoint for an API Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, endpoint

I recently upgraded from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4 and am now having trouble with one of my app's endpoints.

I'm trying to get an external service (Hellosign) to POST some JSON to my app after a user performs an action. For this to go through, my endpoint has to return a 200 HTTP code and a response body containing the following text: "Hello API Event Received"

This worked fine in Rails 3.2, but I'm having trouble doing this in Rails 4. I'd set up a route for this in `config/routes.rb`

`post 'document' => 'requests#document'`

My User model includes `has_many :requests`, and my Request model includes `belongs_to :account`. I'm using the latest version of Devise.

A stripped-down version of the Requests Controller is as follows:

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:document]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:document]

  def document
    render text: "Hello API Event Received"
    @json = JSON.parse(params["json"])
  end
end
```

I skip Devise authentication and verifying the authenticity token for the `document` action so that it can actually receive the POST from the API, which has its own authentication protocols.

THE PROBLEM: I'm getting a message from the API that the callback is failing, with an 'Access denied' error. When I check the production logs in Heroku, I get a `ERROR invalid body size` error message.

My best guess is that something has changed in Rails 4 with Devise and I can no longer use the `before_filter` and `skip_before_action` bits to allow the `document` action to serve as a public-facing endpoint.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it's weird that you parse the json AFTER rendering the response. is that intended?

Comment: did you try posting to that endpoint yourself?

Comment: Well, I thought I needed to relay the message that the event was received before parsing the data. It had worked in the Rails 3.2 version.  And I did try sending a post myself, via Net::HTTP; I received `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: What does Devise have to do with it? If you're only using this for a public endpoint, why do you need to authenticate using Devise? Why don't you use `skip_before_filter` as so: `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :documents`

Comment: Hi Rich. This is a stripped-down controller that doesn't show other actions requiring user authentication. My thinking was that I hadn't excepted the `document` action from Devise authentication in a Rails 4-acceptable manner. Per the Devise documentation, you're supposed to specify `before_action :authenticate_user!`, and so I believe I need to do that and then except the `document` action, right?

Answer (score 0):

Grrr, I found out the problem. The endpoint I specified to the API used `http` rather than `https`.  Everything works swimmingly now after supplying `https` to the HelloSign API. However, the endpoint I'd supplied (with `http`) had worked with Rails 3.2 even after I'd added the SSL in my app...what in the Rails 4 upgrade made this fail? And how to make sense of the `ERROR invalid body size' message? Anyways, thanks to all who supplied suggestions!